# Does DB connection is alive when only 1 connection is being used in application that having 4 db connection setting?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, connection

I am using PHP/Laravel for my API system. There are 4 database connections to a different db servers with a difference platform function. All MYSQL.

My question is if there is one(1) api request but the function only related to one(1) DB connection(the 3 DB conn is using for another type of request/function), does the other 3 connection is alive as a tread to contribute a new connection for the server?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel supports persistent connections where you specify it in your config/database.php file

[More on persistent connections here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/persistent-connection-to-mysql-database-in-laravel-30-50-connection-pooling)

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to that be would be NO, not all database connections will be active. Only those DB connections will be active which are hooked to the model(s), which you are accessing/performing Eloquent or DB Queries on.

So in your case since you are using multiple database connections, you would be defining respective connection on each model e.g.     `protected $connection = 'mysql2';` so when you perform any DB operation on this model then only 'mysql2' connection will be active.

> P.S. mysql2 is the name of one of the database connections specified
>   in your database.php